# How to fetch values from SQLite data except numeric?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is there a way to fetch only non-alphanumeric values from a SQLite database?

My database values has something like 23abc abc21 but I want to fetch only abc abc.

I have tried using REGEXP_REPLACE, LIKE keyword but its not working in SQLite. I want to execute this in android apps.

Comment: he already mentioned in question heading. its SQLite

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This on**

```
String firstname1 = "23abc";
firstname1 = firstname1.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]","");
System.out.println(firstname1);
```

Comment: How do I omit only numbers but retain the rest for instance my data is 12abc 1abc "abc", abc and when I pull the data I want the result to be abc abc "abc", abc

Comment: not understand what you can say "How do I omit only"

Comment: For example firstname = "12abc 'abc'"; When I fetch the value I want the result like this  firstname = abc 'abc' .... meaning remove only numbers but keeping letters coma, space, semi-colon etc.

Comment: Okay understand you have required coma , spcace and semicolan right.           firstname1 = firstname1.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z',; ]","");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144912/discussion-between-ratilal-chopda-and-isaac).

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like that

```
select * from table WHERE value LIKE '^[A-z]+$'
```